# PHP - efficient way of adding multidimensional array values to a specific key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array which contains some ID's based on filters a user has chosen to "find" or "exclude" from a search. Each set of filters is grouped by a key (65 in the example below):

```
$cache_data = ['filters' => [
        65 => [
            'find' => [
                167
            ],
            'exclude' => [
                169,
                171
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I want to add some more ID's to the `find` array whilst retaining any that are already there: 167 in this case. The values in the `exclude` array need to remain untouched. Assume I want to add the following 4 values to `find`:

```
$to_be_added = [241, 242, 285, 286];
```

I need to target the filters based on their group ID (65 in this case) and merge in my new values using `array_merge()`:

```
$existing_filters = ($cache_data['filters'][65]);
$merged = array_merge($existing_filters['find'], $to_be_added);
```

I then rewrite `$cache_data['filters'][65]` by using `$merged` with the `find` key, and keep the values that were already there in `exclude`:

```
$cache_data['filters'][65] = [ 
        'find' => $merged,
        'exclude' => $existing_filters['exclude']
    ];
```

The output for this, `print_r($cache_data['filters'][65]);` is exactly as I want:

```
Array
(
    [find] => Array
        (
            [0] => 167
            [1] => 241
            [2] => 242
            [3] => 285
            [4] => 286
        )

    [exclude] => Array
        (
            [0] => 169
            [1] => 171
        )

)
```

However I'm wondering if there is an easier or more efficient way to achieve the same thing?

Using PHP 7.2.10

Comment: `$cache_data['filters'][65]['find'] += $to_be_added;`?

Comment: The `+` operator will override int keys - I guess OP will not love it...

Comment: @dWinder - it must keep the existing values that were in `find`  (167) as well as add the new ones (241, 242, 285, 286).

Comment: I know - that why I think using `+` is not good for you

Comment: [u_mulders answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55239913/1155833) is pretty much what you had in the question, just as a one-liner. What is it you were hoping to get when asking `if there is an easier or more efficient way to achieve the same thing?` Were you hoping for different ways of writing to do the same? Or perhaps after more performant ways to do the same?

Comment: anything that could be seen as an improvement really. The code @u_mulder has provided is more readable so I prefer this. If you have any further improvements whether in terms of readability, performance or anything else, please feel free to post an answer and I'll take  a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oneliner:

```
$cache_data['filters'][65]['find'] = array_merge(
    $cache_data['filters'][65]['find'], 
    $to_be_added
);
```

Using

```
$cache_data['filters'][65]['find'] += $to_be_added;
```

is **not safe** because in this case key value `241` which is under key `0` will be ignored, as `$cache_data['filters'][65]['find']` already has key `0` with value `167`.

Comment: The "oneliner" answer is correct because as specified it must keep the existing values of `find` (167) and add the new ones (241...286). I can confirm your oneliner solution works.